# how to find properties in right click Contextmenu of C# web browser

Tags: c#, browser, contextmenu

Hi i have a c# application and an embedded browser in it,its task is to find a link and then right click on it and click on properties!

mouse moves programmatically,so i need to find properties in righ click menu!

can you help me how to do this?

i tried pressing 'r' after right click but it didn't work on some computers!

so i need to do it by moving mouse!

here is my code for finding a link and right clicking:

```
int x = getXoffset(link);
int y = getYoffset(link);
webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(x, y);
Linker.Win32.POINT p2 = new Linker.Win32.POINT();
webBrowser1.Focus();
p2.x = webBrowser1.Left + 10;
p2.y = webBrowser1.Top + 5;
Linker.Win32.ClientToScreen(this.Handle, ref p2);
Linker.Win32.SetCursorPos(p2.x, p2.y);
MouseOperations.GetCursorPosition();

MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftDown);
MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.RightDown);
MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.RightUp);
```

Any other idea for reaching properties on right click meny is welcomed

Comment: or is there any way to count items in right click menu and then select the last item which is properties?

Comment: what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: as i explained my application finds a link for example when it loaded www.example.com it finds link named : test and then right clicks on int and then i want to open the properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
        public static void PressKey(Keys key, bool up)
        {
            const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
            const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
            if (up)
            {
                keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
            }
            else
            {
                keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");//Your link
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted); 
        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Find your link and right click(automatically by your code)
            webBrowser1.Document.MouseDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_MouseDown);
        }

        void Document_MouseDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.MouseButtonsPressed == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                PressKey(Keys.P, true);
                PressKey(Keys.P, false);
            }
        }
```